# Why are questions being edited with nonsense text?

Tags: support, status-completed

I noticed a question posted to the front page with a title of "jfklsad jfklsdj flksdj flksd flskdjf sldkj fklsd jfklsd jfklsd jfksld jflskdfj sdiojfsladfk ;sd".

Thinking that this was finally my chance to earn my "Citizen Patrol" badge, I opened the question only to find that the question was normal.

I opened the [user page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/374436/ginius) for "ginius", the user who posted the question, and sorted by "Most Recent". As I refreshed the page, I saw titles with gibberish text appear, then disappear as a high-rep user would roll back the question to its original state. As an example, look at [this revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3126452/revisions). To my knowledge, this is still occurring (8:37PM PST).

What's going on?

---

Edit: The account in question has been "temporarily suspended", so it looks like someone caught it. In the future, what actions should lower-rep users such as myself take when several of a user's posts are being modified? Should we just flag the affected posts, or is there a way to bring a particular **user** to the attention of a moderator?

Comment: wow, that was some pretty crappy editing. What could he have been thinking?

Comment: In the future, I guess this won't happen too much unless someone feels pissed of (which I guess was [the case here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4281066/revisions) after revision 4...), credentials (or [session cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firesheep)...) are compromised: one needs quite some reputation to get edit rights, and as one can see the "fun" of abuse doesn't live too long.

Comment: @Greg, it seems to me that this user tried to re-use an old question for a new question (in this post: [revision 4](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4281066/revisions) and up) and then lost their temper when folks rolled back that change. If true, then too bad someone still doesn't know how things work after over 50 questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flagging is your best first response. You can also email the team@ address for the site you are on.